# Retry wait if loader is still present on the page

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I’m working with the app which is pretty unstable in terms of time of loading data. I have already set my waitFor timeout to 15s and I don’t want to increase it anymore.
My tests are running in CI and often I have to re-run everything because ONE element hasn’t loaded in time.

Also I don’t want to use some `bail` techniques or retry the entire test.

My idea is to wait for the element and if the element with locator `.loader` is still present on the page I want to retry the wait.

So I’m looking for the best way to implement this (Promise maybe?)

```
function waitWithRetry(elementLocator, retryCount) {
    while (retryCount > 0) {
        try {
            $(`${elementLocator}`).waitForDisplayed();
        } catch (e) {
            if ($('.loader').isDisplayed()) {
                retryCount--;
            } else {
                throw new Error(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want to wait until the loader is gone and also the wait should be retried for retryCount times. right?

Comment: Not really. I don't want to wait the loader is gone. Loader is some kind of trigger (or flag?): "If it is present then retry the wait"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will retry until the loader element is available and `retryCount` times once the element is not visible.

```
function waitWithRetry(elementLocator, retryCount) {
    while (retryCount > 0) {
        try {
            $(`${elementLocator}`).waitForDisplayed();
        } catch (e) {
            if ($('.loader').isDisplayed() && retryCount === 1) {
               throw new Error(e);
            }
             retryCount--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In ` if ($('.loader').isDisplayed())` condition you will never reduce the `retryCount` if .`loader` is present. Meaning if loader persists on the page forever you will get the infinite loop

Comment: But that is what I understand from `when Loader is some kind of trigger (or flag?): "If it is present then retry the wait"`

Comment: Maybe you should put your problem in more detailed way so that I can modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: you got the idea absolutely right. What am I saying in this specific situation that if loader will never be gone, then the retry count won't decrease. Meaning you will get stuck in the infinite loop. The idea is to try `retryCount` times if the loader is present after a last try then throw an error.

Comment: Alright. How about now? :) if you feel something is still missing, I would really appreciate it if you can add more details to your question. :)